# Problem with \IfSubStringInString and special characters

Tags: input-encodings, strings

It seems that `IfSubStringInString` has a problem if the sub string contains umlauts or other non-ASCII characters, as is illustrated by the following example:

```
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{substr}
\begin{document}

\IfSubStringInString{Muller}{Müller}{Müller}{no Müller}

\IfSubStringInString{ller}{Müller}{Müller}{no Müller}

\IfSubStringInString{Müller}{Müller}{Müller}{no Müller}
\end{document}
```

Which produces the following output:

```
no Müller
Müller
ller2
üüllerMüllerMüllerno Müller
```

Apparently the first two calls to `IfSubStringInString` work, the third fails.

Is there a way to work around this?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Use [`xstring`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xstring):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{xstring}
\begin{document}

\IfSubStr{Muller}{Müller}{Müller}{no Müller}

\IfSubStr{ller}{Müller}{Müller}{no Müller}

\IfSubStr{Müller}{Müller}{Müller}{no Müller}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you input `ü` under the `utf8` option, LaTeX transforms it into `\IeC{\"u}`. The `substr` package uses `\protected@edef` to store the string and the substring to look for, but later on it uses `\edef` and neither `\IeC` nor `\"` can be used there.

A possible strategy is to “detokenize” the token lists obtained at this point, that represent anyway the strings we have to deal with. Well, in with this strategy `Müller` and `M\IeC{\"u}ller` would be considered the same, but this doesn't seem to be a problem as `\IeC` should never be directly used in a document.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{substr}

\makeatletter % fix the strings so \edef makes no harm later on
\renewcommand\su@ExpandTwoArgs[3]{%
  \protected@edef\su@SubString{#1}%
  \protected@edef\su@String{#2}%
  % ADDITION: detokenize the strings
  \edef\su@SubString{\detokenize\expandafter{\su@SubString}}%
  \edef\su@String{\detokenize\expandafter{\su@String}}%
  % END OF ADDITION
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter#3%
  \expandafter\expandafter\expandafter{%
    \expandafter\su@SubString\expandafter
  }\expandafter{\su@String}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\IfSubStringInString{Muller}{Müller}{Müller}{no Müller}

\IfSubStringInString{ller}{Müller}{Müller}{no Müller}

\IfSubStringInString{Müller}{Müller}{Müller}{no Müller}

\end{document}
```

[image]